# Decode facebook graphql body?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to capture facebook https request from facebook android.

I can capture requests, but their body is encoded and I cannot understand these informations in the request's body. Below is curl of request that I have captured with its body

```sh
curl --location --request POST 'https://graph.facebook.com/graphql?locale=en_US' \
--header 'Host: graph.facebook.com' \
--header 'X-Fb-Sim-Hni: 310270' \
--header 'X-Fb-Net-Hni: 310260' \
--header 'Content-Encoding: gzip' \
--header 'User-Agent: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 9; Xiaomi Redmi Note 7 Build/PI) [FBAN/FB4A;FBAV/315.0.0.47.113;FBPN/com.facebook.katana;FBLC/en_US;FBBV/285966838;FBCR/Android;FBMF/Genymotion;FBBD/Android;FBDV/Xiaomi Redmi Note 7;FBSV/9;FBCA/x86:null;FBDM/{density=2.625,width=1080,height=2214};FB_FW/1;FBRV/287051585;]' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'X-Tigon-Is-Retry: False' \
--header 'X-Fb-Rmd: state=NO_MATCH' \
--header 'X-Fb-Device-Group: 1672' \
--header 'X-Fb-Friendly-Name: RelayFBNetwork_GemstoneProfilePreloadableNonSelfViewQuery' \
--header 'X-Fb-Request-Analytics-Tags: unknown' \
--header 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
--header 'X-Fb-Http-Engine: Liger' \
--header 'X-Fb-Client-Ip: True' \
--header 'X-Fb-Server-Cluster: True' \
--header 'Content-Length: 653' \
--header 'Connection: close' \
--data-raw 'x1fx8bx08x00x00x00x00x00x00x00x95x94xc1x92xa20x10x86x9fFxcfx0ax83xe2xc1Cxc0 (x12x840xae\Rx19x09xcax18x08Cpvxf5xe9x17xc6xb1jwux1c7Ux84Cxf7xd7xe9xfaxfbOxe8fxc3xa4$xb5xd8xb3bx0cAxb3"x1ax03xfdx95x03x03Xxf3x99Mxd7x9c>xc5xe6>x8fx8dxb2x98yxbdaxb5x828xd7c@xcbxd1"xf8xe1xcdx8eG/x9fxa5Sx93xbapxefxcexa1x95x8axb5x16xbcxecxa4:x10kcxebzxxbax92exbdx1cxe5xec-x06|xe7O^x0fxdakxdd?dxa7x1exfax95x97x8bxa1xa5xb9xd4*xd9nxe3xadxd6=xf7$b0xa7xc2x10axa0xbcxb1xd84f\xe6xebxcarExcdxbd}lxe8Zlxc4&^x0eph=x95xcaAU*%xe2xbaxdeM_x08-3xb2xa1x9cxb3x8al8x95rx1c0Nx8fx0bx91xb0xaaxb8xc4+xf6Fxd2*cExc2x8fxa4xa09x1bOY.kQ0xbfx12ixc6x9bx1fxe3x82&xf4x853Ox14!xe3xe9sxc6~.x0fxac:vxdfix95xb5x019xeex0cx8dx8exa2|"xffT xbex8d0"6txa66nxb2:*xe8+xa3AG1xbfCVxcex04xdbx9fDOxefxdd%Bx1bxadHx88Qxe0xc0x90x18x919x87x9fgxd5xd5x81xdd%-x88Mx9b,#x18Ax82xd1txeaBb x8cxd1xa2xa9x09/URxcaxe5#excex8dx9bxc0xc7x0exf2xc2GYxc7xc30x80!x86x93[bxa9xf7xb5xbax82xffx92Mxbbxcfx86xc4Fx0bHxc2xc8hxbexc0x02&|Txb5&xd5wx1axadxaex1bxd6x9fxfex87xfcxa3xdbx0bx98xb2zxb3sx8ax9aULxd6!+jxe3x18IV=xaaxe6x87x15|x10x86>x0a01x1dxbcxfex8axdcxde"#ox82Hx08Mxe4Mx88x8bxd0xfcx86x1bxbeUxe7xecFx14xb9x0bx80x1b;x01xcfx83xc1xd7xedxcbxfcxdaHxcfx0e\xc1xe0<\`xb6njxdcx0dptxedxa9xf2xcc9xc99xd2xecxea@Wx94~x7fxa0ixfdxe1xa8xa7xabmxe0#Uxeexc4x81'\''V+xefx826xdb*xabwxeduxbexa1xed9x15x16xedxfdx0e<[xe4x97xfexdaxb9l+Zgxa2xb8x82xf2xb6hVlMZ$YBk&}xbaeavbxe7Txb53x9ctx9bIxbe7ORx9dxe5xcdti^xcaq+g7x11x1bx92%cMxedxebx9a6x1axa8xbaxd2x1fxa8Cxf57x90x9dxcdMx91x05x00x00'
```

Does anyone know how to decode that body ? Thanks !

Comment: Are you talking about the `--data-raw` value? That looks like hex encoding, always a literal `x` character, followed by two hex digits …

Comment: @CBroe that's right, I am trying to decode `--data-raw`. Do you know how to do that ?

Comment: You can try and extract the hex values and convert them to decimal, resp. see if the byte values interpreted in any specific character encoding have any particular meaning; but I would not be on it, it might be that there’s an additional level of encryption or obfuscation going on.